# Each cell with different layout in TableView, how is scroll optimised?

Tags: uitableview, reuseidentifier

If I have a UITableView with each cell having a different layout. For example, cell 1 has one text field, cell two has two text fields and so on, in this case height of tableview cell varies based on how many text fields it has one below the other. For this specific scenario, will I be able to make use of reuseIndetifier and reuse the cell.

Is tableView reuseIdentifier useful only when layout of each cell is same? Or can I still reuse cells by making use of single identifier but adding textfields in cellForRowAtIndexPath dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a bit. I can do some basic reuse of cells by having a cell with empty template/blank cell. But in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I can dynamically create text fields and add. This works perfectly fine, allowing me to add as many number of views required to be added to TableView cell. I am using blank cell, which will be reused on scroll. However I am not sure that will be the impact on performance when I create and add UI elements dynamically to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Any ideas there?